# establishing encryption on csr1010 bluetooth low energy

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, bluetooth-lowenergy, csr

I need to transfer data over bluetooth Low Energy between an iPhone and a csr1010. I know it uses an AES encryption, but is it default, or do I need to set it up? can I change its parameters, to set up different levels of encryption?
if so, how is it possible?
I googled around, but did not come accross anything helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: If it is standard Bluetooth encryption then you shouldn't need to do anything - the Core Bluetooth framework will prompt the user for a pairing pin in order to establish the keys when required

Comment: Thanks! Is it present in bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: Yes, BT4.0/BLE includes encryption where required - where an attribute is flagged as requiring encryption, a pairing operation will be performed on the first read/write of that attribute.